# math equation goes out of the right margin

Tags: math-mode, margins, math-operators, overleaf

I have the following latex text written in overleaf document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\textbf{Assign each array of weights to the relative actor name}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Daniel Craig} = 
\begin{bmatrix} -0.42056742 & -0.3540595 & -0.25417486 & -0.50596726 & -0.29918054\\ -0.23971583 & -0.39325562 & -0.35581827 & -0.3175518 & -0.2992685\\ -0.26149312 & -0.3268542 & -0.34264958 & -0.50005287 & -0.41450888\\ \ldots (m=60)
\end{bmatrix} = shape(5x60)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Tobey Maguire} = \begin{bmatrix} -0.30834767 & -0.26681098 & -0.2173222  & -0.11151562 & -0.27951762\\ -0.1721798 & -0.25406063 & -0.38693774 & -0.19798501 & -0.257399\\ -0.05970115 & -0.2399106 & -0.21202469 & -0.28024384 & -0.2577843\\ \ldots (m=60) 
\end{bmatrix}= shape(5x60)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, both equations go out of the right margin, like is shown in the image below,
[image]

I know that there are many similar questions on this matter, however, I am new in Latex and I don't understand how to apply most of the solutions I found on my much simple case. Thank you in advance for any suggestion and I apologize if this is a duplicate.

**Update 1**
Based on an answer on the comments section, by using this command \textrm{Tobey Maguire} I managed to overcome the extra space and wrong names problem, so I got this,

[image]

**Update 2 - relative to the reproducible code added**

I opened a new Overleaf blank page and I added the code above (with packages)
And I got the following shot,

[image]

Since the 2 screenshots added earlier are from a pre-defined template I don't know where the page margins are. Also, I don't know the default Latex margins of Overleaf. Because you can see in the screenshots that the letters are much smaller. How can I modify the page margins in Latex?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC Hey, what do you mean compilable? Like also libraries (packages) I used? Sorry It's my 1st time here. :)

Comment: @NikSp: A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) also contains the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: you should not have `\ \\ ` in an equation (it doesn't do anything useful) and  words should not be in math italic so `\textrm{David Lewis}` but we can not tell you how to make it fit if you do not show an example showing how wide your page is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At first \textrm{David Lewis} fxed the extra spaces and staff...Let me edit my question

Comment: @NikSp LaTeX is a language that, like C, Pascal and others, is compiled on the contrary of javascript and PHP which are interpreted. Thus, a document is fully compilable when you only need to copy and paste the code to produce the PDF output. This saves users from having to search painfully for the packages your document needs to produce the PDF. Then, as leandriis says, having an MWE is the basis of the questions, see on this subject [How to make a minimum example](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need to give the values to so many decimal places? If so you need to shrink the font something like this, but if possible I'd print at normal size but use 3 decimal places or whatever is suitable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\paragraph{Assign each array of weights to the relative actor name}
\small
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\rlap{\text{David Lewis}}\\
 &= \begin{bmatrix} -0.42056742 & -0.3540595 & -0.25417486 & -0.50596726 & -0.29918054\\ -0.23971583 & -0.39325562 & -0.35581827 & -0.3175518 & -0.2992685\\ -0.26149312 & -0.3268542 & -0.34264958 & -0.50005287 & -0.41450888\\ \ldots (m=60)
\end{bmatrix}\\
& = \operatorname{shape}(5\times60)
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
\rlap{\text{James Gandolfini}}\\
& = \begin{bmatrix} -0.30834767 & -0.26681098 & -0.2173222  & -0.11151562 & -0.27951762\\ -0.1721798 & -0.25406063 & -0.38693774 & -0.19798501 & -0.257399\\ -0.05970115 & -0.2399106 & -0.21202469 & -0.28024384 & -0.2577843\\ \ldots (m=60) 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \operatorname{shape}(5\times60)
\end{split}
\end{align}
%no!!\ \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. It seems to fit perfectly to my case.

Comment: From your answer, I can understand how new I am in Latex, that even there is a shape operator and I was using a word for it. Thanks again David, very well structured answer and actually helps me for similar cases

Comment: @NikSp there isn't a shape operator predefined but `\operatorname{foobar}`  makes a roman foobar operator with the same spacing as `\log` or `\sin` predefined operators

Answer (score 3):

You need to reduce the font size, if you want to fit such big objects.

I propose a solution with `siunitx` and a `tabular` built in text mode via `lrbox`.

You can choose the font size as an optional argument to `weightmatrix`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\DeclareMathOperator{\shape}{shape}
\newsavebox{\weightmatrixbox}
\newenvironment{weightmatrix}[1][\normalsize]
 {%
  \left[
  \begin{lrbox}{\weightmatrixbox}#1% a size changing command
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}*{5}{S[table-format=-1.8]}@{}}%
 }
 {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}\usebox{\weightmatrixbox}\right]}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos}
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\subsection*{Assign each array of weights to the relative actor name}

\begin{align}
&\text{Daniel Craig} \notag\\
& = 
\begin{weightmatrix}[\footnotesize]
  -0.42056742 & -0.3540595  & -0.25417486 & -0.50596726 & -0.29918054 \\
  -0.23971583 & -0.39325562 & -0.35581827 & -0.3175518  & -0.2992685  \\
  -0.26149312 & -0.3268542  & -0.34264958 & -0.50005287 & -0.41450888 \\
  \ldots (m=60)
\end{weightmatrix} \\
& = \shape(5 \times 60) \notag \\[2ex]
&\text{Tobey Maguire} \notag\\
& =
\begin{weightmatrix}[\footnotesize]
  -0.30834767 & -0.26681098 & -0.2173222  & -0.11151562 & -0.27951762 \\
  -0.1721798  & -0.25406063 & -0.38693774 & -0.19798501 & -0.257399   \\
  -0.05970115 & -0.2399106  & -0.21202469 & -0.28024384 & -0.2577843  \\
  \ldots (m=60) 
\end{weightmatrix} \\
&= \shape(5 \times 60) \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Way too much advanced for my level of Latex knowledge. An also exceptional answer. Thanks for your reply egreg!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to position the page in `landscape` mode.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\textbf{Assign each array of weights to the relative actor name}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Daniel Craig} = 
\begin{bmatrix} -0.42056742 & -0.3540595 & -0.25417486 & -0.50596726 & -0.29918054\\ -0.23971583 & -0.39325562 & -0.35581827 & -0.3175518 & -0.2992685\\ -0.26149312 & -0.3268542 & -0.34264958 & -0.50005287 & -0.41450888\\ \ldots (m=60)
\end{bmatrix} = shape(5x60)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Tobey Maguire} = \begin{bmatrix} -0.30834767 & -0.26681098 & -0.2173222  & -0.11151562 & -0.27951762\\ -0.1721798 & -0.25406063 & -0.38693774 & -0.19798501 & -0.257399\\ -0.05970115 & -0.2399106 & -0.21202469 & -0.28024384 & -0.2577843\\ \ldots (m=60) 
\end{bmatrix}= shape(5x60)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```